# Memory Leak in C-extension for Python

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

This is the first time I am writing a C-extension for python and you can see my ugly and probably super inefficient C++ implementation of a convolution. I have a problem with the memory management. Each time I call this function in python it consumes about 500MB of memory (for a batch of size 100x112x112x3 and a kernel of size 3x3x3x64) and doesn't free it afterwards. Do I have do take care about reference counting, even if this is not a class-method? Or do I have to free up memory manually somewhere in the code? Note that I excluded all the error checks for a better overview. Thanks.

```
PyObject* conv2d(PyObject*, PyObject* args)

{
    PyObject* data;
    PyObject* shape;
    PyObject* kernel;
    PyObject* k_shape;
    int stride;

    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOOOi", &data, &shape, &kernel, &k_shape, &stride);

    Py_ssize_t dims = PyTuple_Size(shape);
    Py_ssize_t kernel_dims = PyTuple_Size(k_shape);

    int shape_c[3];
    int k_shape_c[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < kernel_dims; i++)
    {
        if (i < dims)
        {
            shape_c[i] = PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GetItem(shape, i));
        }
        k_shape_c[i] = PyLong_AsLong(PyTuple_GetItem(k_shape, i));
    }

    PyObject* data_item, kernel_item;
    PyObject* ret_array = PyList_New(0);
    double conv_val, channel_sum;

    for (int oc = 0; oc < k_shape_c[3]; oc++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < shape_c[0]; row += stride)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < shape_c[1]; col += stride)
            {
                channel_sum = 0;
                for (int ic = 0; ic < shape_c[2]; ic++)
                {
                    conv_val = 0;
                    for (int k_row = 0; k_row < k_shape_c[0]; k_row++)
                    {
                        for (int k_col = 0; k_col < k_shape_c[1]; k_col++)
                        {
                            data_item = PyList_GetItem(data, row + k_row);
                            if (!data_item)
                            {
                                PyErr_Format(PyExc_IndexError, "Index out of bounds");
                                return NULL;
                            }
                            data_item = PyList_GetItem(data_item, col + k_col);
                            data_item = PyList_GetItem(data_item, ic);
                            kernel_item = PyList_GetItem(kernel, k_row);
                            kernel_item = PyList_GetItem(kernel_item, k_col);
                            kernel_item = PyList_GetItem(kernel_item, ic);
                            kernel_item = PyList_GetItem(kernel_item, oc);
                            conv_val += PyFloat_AsDouble(data_item) * PyFloat_AsDouble(kernel_item);
                        }
                    }
                    channel_sum += conv_val;
                }
                PyList_Append(ret_array, PyFloat_FromDouble(channel_sum));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret_array;
}
```

Comment: Everything wrong. You **must** check the return value of **each and every** `Py_*` call and act accordingly. If a failure occurs you **must** manually decref each and every pointer that are dangling / or the list.

Comment: And the truth is you should **not** use the Python float conversions every single time in an inner loop if you're after speed. And most likely Numpy will already be faster than 99 % of the concepts you could come up so why not use Numpy anyway?

Comment: Please pick *one* language. C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: Another important question: does it **always** consume 500M **more** every time you call the function in the program **and** you have `del`d the reference to the list.

Comment: The float objects alone would consume 90M of memory

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Actually I did check all of the Py_ calls, I just assumed, these are not important for memory management so I excluded them for stackoverflow. I added one of the error checks in the code. So you mean I have to add Py_DECREF(data_item) in the if statement? But how could this solve my memory problem, as I don't have any call issues? (otherwise I would get an error message). And yes it consumes additional 500MB for every batch of 100 images. what do you mean by del the reference to the list?

Comment: I know of course that there are existing and fast enough implementations of  convolution, but it's not my goal to implement a fast convolution.

Comment: so then the problem is the memory increment: do you consistently get 500M more each time you call the convolution function?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes

Comment: Please provide a test program. There are no leaks that I can see

Comment: I found the culprit now. Instead of using PyList_Append i initialized the list to the right length and filled it by indexing. This is even a whole lot faster. Just out of interest, do you know what could be the problem with append? Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leak comes from:

```
PyList_Append(ret_array, PyFloat_FromDouble(channel_sum));
```

`PyFloat_FromDouble` creates a new reference, `PyList_Append` takes shared ownership of the reference (it doesn't *steal*/*consume* the reference). When using `PyList_Append` and you want the `list` to take ownership of your own reference, you must explicitly release your reference after appending, e.g. (error checks omitted):

```
PyObject *pychannel_sum = PyFloat_FromDouble(channel_sum);
PyList_Append(ret_array, pychannel_sum);
Py_DECREF(pychannel_sum);
```

The alternative (and faster if suitable) solution is to preallocate the `list` to the correct size, and fill in the entries with `PyList_SetItem`/`PyList_SET_ITEM`, both of which *steal* a reference, rather than incrementing the reference count. In general, APIs that don't explicitly mention reference stealing won't, and you'll need to police your own reference counts.

Note that memory-wise, individual `PyFloat`s are quite a bit more expensive than C `double`s (which they wrap); on a 64 bit system, each `PyFloat` in a `list` consumes 32 bytes (eight for the pointer in the `list`, 24 for the `PyFloat` itself), vs. eight for the raw C `double`.

You may want to look into using [Python's `array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) (creating an `array` of the correct size/type, using the buffer protocol to make a C level view of it, then filling in the buffer); the code will be a tad more complex, but the memory usage will drop by a factor of 4x.  `numpy` types will provide the same advantage (and the result may be used more flexibly).